# Can my protected tweet be seen by the recipient who doesn't follow me?

Tags: twitter

So the description for protected tweets are:

> Only confirmed followers have access to @foo's Tweets and complete profile. Click the "Follow" button to send a follow request.

But what if I tweet to a user who doesn't follow me, will he/she be able to see my tweet?

```
Hey, @userwhodoesnotfollowme can you see this tweet?
```

Comment: From the Twitter help docs: [About Public and Protected Tweets](https://support.twitter.com/articles/14016-about-public-and-protected-tweets), "@Replies you send to people who aren't following you will not be seen by those users (because you have not given them permission to see your Tweets)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they will not be able to see the tweet.

Comment: that's lame.. :\

Comment: It's consistent, and prevents accidental breach of expected privacy. *Eg. "Hey `@myfriend`, did you notice the tweet by `@myenemy`, any idea on how to respond?"* It would be very good if Twitter would give some sort of notification of this behaviour when sending the tweet, though.

Comment: exactly, something like `hey, you mentioned @myfriend but he doesn't seem to follow you ergo he/she won't be able to see your tweet.` but I know it now anyway so it doesn't matter.